# Glibc Configuration Error

Tags: linux, arm, glibc, autoconf, linux-from-scratch

I am working though the Linux from scratch book when I encountered an error configuring Glibc (step 5.7):

```
checking for sysdeps preconfigure fragments... aarch64 alpha arm configure: error: Old ABI no longer supported
```

I am using:

```
../glibc-2.20/configure                             \
  --prefix=/tools                               \
  --host=$LFS_TGT                               \
  --build=$(../glibc-2.20/scripts/config.guess) \
  --disable-profile                             \
  --enable-kernel=2.6.32                        \
  --with-headers=/tools/include                 \
  libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes                     \
  libc_cv_ctors_header=yes                      \
  libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes
```

I have had no trouble until now. My $LFS_TGT=armv6l-lfs-linux-gnueabihf

Answer (score 1):

you should upgrade to the latest glibc release.  most likely you don't have a compiler yet, so when glibc attempts to run a compile test, it fails and assumes you're trying to use an OABI toolchain.

this was fixed here:
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=34d97d87bb1c08e34d08a9d4be24a3b1d53a4ddb